# show a conclusion from the homomorphism $\phi : \Bbb R _{>0} \to \Bbb R$ such that $\phi (r) = \log(r)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I need two show homomorphism and get a conclusion from iso1 in the following:

a) I have $\phi : \Bbb R _{>0} \to \Bbb R$

$\phi (r) = \log(r)$

I assume here that $\Bbb R _{>0}$ is with multiplication and $\Bbb R$ is with addition??  Is that correct to assume ?

because I don't have this information in the question. if it is with addition then I don't know how to make homomorphism.

so i get $\ker (\phi) = 1 =
 e$

so my conclusion  from iso1 is that

$\Bbb R _{>0} \cong \Bbb R$

which dosen't make sense to me..

b) I have $\phi : \Bbb R^* \to \Bbb R$

$\phi (r) = log(|r|)$

again I assume that $\Bbb R$ is with addition

and I get to the conclusion that

$\Bbb R^*/Sign \cong \Bbb R$

which again dosen't make sense.

any help will be very appreciated

Comment: for the first one - I don't get how there is a one to one function between R+ and R . how can it be ? what about all the negatives in R.  About the second one - what you wrote makes sense for me.. but I didn't get that result because the image is R not R>0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumptions--after all, $\Bbb R_{>0}$ isn't a group under addition, and $\Bbb R$ isn't a group under multiplication.

The thing to keep in mind is that, unlike what we see in finite sets, infinite sets can be in one-to-one correspondence with *proper subsets of themselves*! In fact $\Bbb R$ can be put in one-to-one correspondence with $(a,b)$ for any two $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b,$ but that is not particularly relevant.

You have in fact *proved* that $r\mapsto\log(r)$ is a one-to-one homomorphism $\Bbb R_{>0}\to\Bbb R.$ If you can prove it is surjective, then you have proved that it is actually a *bijection* and so an isomorphism.

From there, since $\Bbb R^*/\{1,-1\}\cong\Bbb R_{>0}$ readily, then the first result gives you another way to verify that $\Bbb R^*/\{1,-1\}\cong\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

They ask you to show *there is a homomorphism* in both cases. It is left for you to make the additional necessary assumptions to do so. Your guess for this is correct, as $\log(xy)=log(x)+log(y)$

As for your surprise about the correct conclusion that you draw, remember you are dealing with the continuum: the whole real line is contained within any connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ is a bijection between $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Mind you, a similar bijection occur for, say the natural numbers, where there are as many even natural numbers as the whole set of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumptions are correct.

To show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism you must show: 
$$\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$$

Define: $\phi(x)=log(x), s.t. \phi: \mathbb{R_{>0}} \to \mathbb{R}$

Consider:

$$\phi(xy)=log(xy)=log(x)+log(y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$$

So we have that $\phi(x)$ is a homomorphism.

Here, $ker(\phi(x))=1$ since $log(1)=0$ where 1,0 are identity elements of the domain and codomain respectively. So you have that the identity of your domain maps to the identity of your codomain.

Thus, $\phi(x)$ mapping between these two groups as defined is an isomorphism and these two groups are isomorphic.

So, why is your observation true? Infinite sets can map 1-1 onto subsets of themselves. Cantor used this to describe the different sizes of infinite sets to show that the cardinality of (0,1) is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Surely you don't mean $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y).$

Comment: In general, yes I do. However, when applied to any particular case we must adapt appropriately. Perhaps you would prefer that I say if (A,*) and (B,+) are groups them the map $f: A \to B$ is a homomorphism if $f(x*y)=f(x)+f(y)$? I think you make a fair point.